# Angular Server Side Rendering Infinit loading no response

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, internationalization, server-side-rendering

I'am traing to add Angular server side redering using this tutorial:
https://angular.io/guide/universal

I'am using i18n translation + material + firebase.

Initially i had to change server.ts file in order to point to right directory (`dist/browser/it`) beacuse of error:

```
 Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "C:\Data\Development\Web\Wor
kingHours4bWeb\dist\WorkingHours4bWeb\browser"
    at Function.render (C:\Data\Development\Web\WorkingHours4bWeb\dist\WorkingHours4
bWeb\server\main.js:128813:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Data\Development\Web\WorkingHours4bWeb\dist\Working
Hours4bWeb\server\main.js:244414:7)
    at C:\Data\Development\Web\WorkingHours4bWeb\dist\WorkingHours4bWeb\server\main.
js:373787:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Data\Development\Web\WorkingHours4bWeb\d
ist\WorkingHours4bWeb\server\main.js:180406:5)
    at next (C:\Data\Development\Web\WorkingHours4bWeb\dist\WorkingHours4bWeb\server
\main.js:133160:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Data\Development\Web\WorkingHours4bWeb\dist\WorkingHours4b
Web\server\main.js:133135:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Data\Development\Web\WorkingHours4bWeb\d
ist\WorkingHours4bWeb\server\main.js:180406:5)
    at C:\Data\Development\Web\WorkingHours4bWeb\dist\WorkingHours4bWeb\server\main.
js:413002:22
    at param (C:\Data\Development\Web\WorkingHours4bWeb\dist\WorkingHours4bWeb\serve
r\main.js:413075:14)
    at param (C:\Data\Development\Web\WorkingHours4bWeb\dist\WorkingHours4bWeb\serve
r\main.js:413086:14)
```

Now my tab is loading without giving any result, no error in de debugger, only loading infinite time and no page result. I have also tried to debug the command `npm run dev:ssr` but i don't have any error.

[image]

(Loading)

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "working-hours4b-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "start0000": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run WorkingHours4bWeb:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/WorkingHours4bWeb/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run WorkingHours4bWeb:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run WorkingHours4bWeb:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.5",
    "@js-joda/core": "^3.2.0",
    "@js-joda/extra": "^0.4.0",
    "@js-joda/locale": "^3.2.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^11.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "firebase": "^8.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "materialize-angular": "^0.7.10",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^11.0.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^11.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.5",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Is there any solution to see the exact error ?

Comment: I think your error is pretty self explaining. It can find index in `C:\Data\Development\Web\Wor
kingHours4bWeb\dist\WorkingHours4bWeb\browser`

Comment: Hi robin, that error was solved with a little change to server.ts. Now, when the path it’s finally found, I got infinite loading

Comment: ANd you've got no errors no where (browser/terminal)?

Comment: No because is not loading, i also traied to debug SSR (i'am using webstorm), but i can't line break inside server.ts . I have traied to create a new test project and it's working (only by including all library from package.json), as soon as i include other source that is using Material, Firebase database and Crashlytics, i got this. Seems that the only way to find the problem is to include project one part at time.

Comment: Does your component call an API to render ? It may be that API call that never ends, depending on your server configuration... Can you connect to your server, and try to call an URL that Angular Universal tries to call ? Note that when you do SSR, you have to be sure both the server AND the browser are able to resolve each call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short story

Most likely this is related with Firebase. Try to:

- Limit the use of `valueChanges()` using `take(1)` or some similar operation.
  For testing purposes, you could replace your entire call to firebase with a mock call that returns an observable or a promise that immediately completes. If it worked, it means your problem is in the call to the database.
- Use different versions of `firebase` and `@angular/fire`.

### Long Story

#### Why limiting `valueChanges()`?

Angular Universal runs your code on the server. If your code generates any async operations or observables that never complete, your server will hang forever as it is waiting for the operation to complete.

`valueChanges()` is necessary on the client to have a "live" stream and reflect DB changes to the UI in realtime. On the server however, this behavior is the opposite of what you need, as you would probably want to fetch some data and render the page.

Your code should detect whether it's running on a browser or on the server and create the appropriate observable (one that completes **after the first emission** for server, one that stays open for browsers).

> **NOTE**
> `valueChanges()` is a common problem in this case, but the same concept applies to any other observable you might have subscribed to in your code.

> **TIP**
> You could use [`UniversalService`](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/Universal%20Module/UniversalService) from the [`@bespunky/angular-zen`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bespunky/angular-zen) library. Just install the library and inject the service where you need it.

#### Why trying different versions?

At some point, there was a version of `@angular/fire` which had a bug where the library had internally left an operation uncompleted, in turn causing a never completing `NgZone` task.

The solution was either upgrading or downgrading, but you had to find the matching `firebase` version.